# Firebase Auth - Swift persistence

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

So basically Firebase is persisting state throughout my app. When I start rebuilding my app  I can
clearly see that the state is saved on the app cache and retrieved back from there.

But the problem is, when I create a new user account from my admin panel, the auth state changes to the newly created user (auth.currentUser), but when trying to change it back to the admin user it does not change any state.
Which is weird because the Firebase docs for `.updateCurrentUser(User)` method tells otherwise.

Look at the code below; I would appreciate any help:

```swift
private func addTransporter() {

        let admin = Auth.auth().currentUser

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { [self] authResult, error in
            guard let newUser = authResult?.user, error == nil else {
                print("Kullanıcı oluşturma hatası: (error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                return
            }


            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            db.collection("users").document(newUser.uid).setData([
                "fullName": naam,
                "email": email,
                "role": "Transporter",
                "id": newUser.uid
            ]) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Firestore'a kaydetme hatası: (error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("Kullanıcı başarıyla eklendi.")
                    self.clearFormAndDismiss()
                    if (admin != nil){
                         Auth.auth().updateCurrentUser(admin!)
                        print("admin acildi (admin)")
                    }else{
                        print("Admin Bulunamadi")
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
private func addTransporter() {
    let admin = Auth.auth().currentUser

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { [self] authResult, error in
        guard let newUser = authResult?.user, error == nil else {
            print("Kullanıcı oluşturma hatası: (error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            return
        }

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").document(newUser.uid).setData([
            "fullName": naam,
            "email": email,
            "role": "Transporter",
            "id": newUser.uid
        ]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Firestore'a kaydetme hatası: (error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Kullanıcı başarıyla eklendi.")
                self.clearFormAndDismiss()
                if let adminUser = admin {
                    Auth.auth().updateCurrentUser(adminUser) { error in
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Auth state güncelleme hatası: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        } else {
                            print("Auth state başarıyla güncellendi.")
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Admin Bulunamadi")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and let me know any.

Comment: ye worked, it was btw for my friend and i m a go backend dev and computer science student, and i helped him with this without having any experience in swift. but i was like confused why it wasnt working, but it was about some syntax and handling stuff. anyways swift looks weird

Comment: good to hear that.

Comment: yea bro, thnx btw